# saxon:evaluate equivalent for MarkLogic xdmp:xslt-eval

Tags: xslt, saxon, marklogic

I need to use a stylesheet that calls `saxon:evaluate()` in MarkLogic. However it throws an error when I try to use `xdmp:xslt-eval` as it is not recognizable by ML as it is saxon specific.

Does anyone have an idea how to overcome this? As far as i know there isn't anything similar to saxon:evaluate() in ML, I know this will be available as default in XSLT 3.0 but that doesn't really help atm. Is there a similar function in MarkLogic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalents are http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unpath http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:value and http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval